# Data import error with d3 when formatting date

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, frontend

I have a csv file with two columns: `year` / `running_total`

| year | running_total |
| --- | --- |
| 1884 | 1 |
| ... | ... |
| 1969 | 50710 |
| ... | ... |

```
// define function to parse time in years format
var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%Y");

var pathToCsv = "q3.csv";       // path to csv
    
    d3.dsv(",", pathToCsv, function (d) {
      return {
        // format data attributes if required
        year : formatTime(d.year),
        running_total : parseInt(d.running_total)
      }
    }).then(function (data) {
      console.log(data); // you should see the data in your browser's developer tools console
```

However, when I checked the data in the console, I see all the values in column `year` is 1969, while the `running_total` shows correctly.

Could anyone tell me what happened?

Comment: It appears as though you want to convert a string into a date object (d3.timeParse) instead of convert a date object into a string (d3.timeFormat), though you may just want to keep the four digit string from the csv in your data, in which case you don't need to use either.

Comment: @AndrewReid Thanks, you're correct.